# JavaScript cycle i++ 5.. 10.. 15

Tags: javascript, cycle

i just beginner in JS, in all tutorials i saw lot of examples like that, but it for cycle 1, 2, 3 etc.

```
for (i=1;i<=20;i++)
```

So, how to create an cycle: 5, 10, 15, 25 etc?

Thnx for any help!

Comment: Hi maybe something like this
for (i=0;i<=20;i+=5) {
  console.log(i)
}

Comment: You could do an inner if block that checks `if i % 5 === 0`

Comment: `for (i = 5; i <= 20; i += 5) { ... }`

Comment: `1, 2, 3...` looks rather like a **sequence** than a **cycle**...

Comment: OP, note that most of these answers don't declare `i` properly (I'm assuming because they're just using your example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i=5;i<=20;i=i+5)
```

I think you are looking for this

Comment: Thank you so much, it's work perfect!

Answer (score 3):

Hi maybe something like this

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i+=5) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: updated your code so that `i` is declared properly.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to change how the value of `i` is updated. You can do it like this:

```
i += 5
```

which is equivalent to

```
i = i + 5
```

Of course, instead of `5` you can put the value that you prefer.
Then you have to change where the `for` loop starts, by setting

```
var i = 5
```

and finally you choose the value at which your loop should stop (for instance, 50). To sum up:

```
for(var i = 5; i < 50; i +=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the right amount for the incrementor.

```js
var i;
for (i = 5; i <= 20; i += 5) {
    document.write(i + '<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create it like this:

```
for(var i=5; i<=20; i+=5)
```

Read it like this:

- Starting at a value 5 for i
- Until i reaches 20
- And increasing i by 5 for every step

Comment: You should declare `i` properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( i=5; i <= 100; i += 5 )
```

Or:

```
var j;
for ( i=1; i <= 100; i += 1 ) {
  j = i * 5;
  // ...
}
```